# Is there a way to make randint() less pseudo and more random?

Tags: python, random

I'm working on a lottery simulator and I'm not quiet happy with the draws generated by randint.

Are there any tricks to make it more random?

Comment: How did you decide it wasn't random enough?

Comment: I'd expect it to be as random as the OS makes possible.

Comment: Most non-statisticians have incorrect intuition about random data.

Comment: Python uses the Mersenne twister generator which is considered to have good random properties for non-cryptographic uses. You need to explain what issue you're seeing with it.

Comment: Also make sure to avoid over-seeding or seeding from a small pool.. since Python 3 rand.seed(None) will use the OS random en-trophy if possible.

Comment: @user1001112 you have an answer, and if you answer people's questions here in the comments, they can help better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

This is because `randint()` is *supposed* to be pseudo-random - it, and the whole `random` module, has that as its entire purpose.

If you want cryptographically-secure randomness, maybe look into the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module instead:

> The [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module is used for generating cryptographically strong random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#module-random) module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.